# Cannot Configure Grails 3 Multiple Data Sources

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have recently attempted to create an application that allows me to compare 3 separate databases for their values.  The databases are 3 Oracle instances which house (essentially) the same database, but in a DEV/TEST/PROD setting.

What I want to do is create one Domain class in GRAILS 3.  I then want to be able to fetch the records which that domain class maps to, but do it for all 3 environments.

From reading the Grails 3 docs, it looks like this should be possible by defining 3 datasources in application.yml (in my example here I define 4):

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        logSql: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:1521:DEV1
    dataSource1:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        logSql: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:1521:DEV1
    dataSource2:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        logSql: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:1521:TEST1
    dataSource3:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        logSql: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:1521:PROD1
```

and then within the domain class' mapping specifying datasources in the mapping:

```
package plsutils

class DmjTypes {
    String code
    String description
    Date insertDate
    String insertUser
    Date modifyDate
    String modifyUser

    String dbEnv

    static mapping = {
        datasources(['dataSource1', 'dataSource2', 'dataSource3'])

        version false
        table name: "CDE_DMJ_TYPES", schema: "MYSCHEMA"

        id generator: 'sequence' ,params:[sequence: 'DMJTY_SEQ']

        columns {
            id column: "DMJTY_ID"
            code column: "DMJTY_CDE"
            description column: "DMJTY_DESCR"
            insertDate column: "INSERT_DTT"
            insertUser column: "INSERT_USER"
            modifyDate column: "MODIFY_DTT"
            modifyUser column: "MODIFY_USER"
            dbEnv formula:'( select inst.instance_name || \'-\' ||     inst.host_name from v$instance inst ) '
        }

    }
}
```

and then, within my controller, I should be able to do something like this:

```
params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
dmjTypesListDev = DmjTypes.dataSource1.list(params)
dmjTypesListTest = DmjTypes.dataSource2.list(params)
dmjTypesListProd = DmjTypes.dataSource3.list(params)
```

I am getting an error upon the first call:

```
URI /dmjTypes/index
Class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message null
Caused by No such property: dataSource1 for class: plsutils.DmjTypes
```

I'm using ojdbc7.jar, connection to Oracle 11g and I'm using Grails 3.0.9.

I can't help but think I'm doing something subtly stupid somewhere.  Can anyone please help me with this?

Cheers,
Allen

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I determined that the above code seems to work.  The problem was that I had recently upgraded the grails version I was using.  Because of a conflict with the existing configuration file that lists the grails version, there were issues.  I updated the config file to have the correct grails version in the gradle.properties file (3.1.1), did a complete clean and rebuild, and it seemed to work.  The lesson here is to take care when upgrading grails versions, even if it is minor version releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I corrected the version of grails referred to in the gradle.properties and performed a complete clean and rebuild, I was able to get it working.  I believe all my issues were because of a version mismatch of the grails I was using to build it.

So, this is the appropriate datasource entry:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@somelocalserver:1521:LOCAL
    one:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@somedevserver:1521:DEV1
    two:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@sometestserver:1521:TEST1
    three:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@someproductionserver:1523:PROD1
```

This is the working domain class:

```
class DmjTypes {
    String code
    String description
    Date insertDate
    String insertUser
    Date modifyDate
    String modifyUser

    String dbEnv

    static mapping = {
        datasources(['one', 'two', 'three'])

        version false
        table name: "CDE_DMJ_TYPES", schema: "MYSCHEMA"

        id generator: 'sequence' ,params:[sequence: 'DMJTY_SEQ']

        columns {
            id column: "DMJTY_ID"
            code column: "DMJTY_CDE"
            description column: "DMJTY_DESCR"
            insertDate column: "INSERT_DTT"
            insertUser column: "INSERT_USER"
            modifyDate column: "MODIFY_DTT"
            modifyUser column: "MODIFY_USER"
            dbEnv formula:'( select inst.instance_name || \'-\' ||     inst.host_name from v$instance inst ) '
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [official documantation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) try *dataSources* keyword:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:
    lookup:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        username: lookup
        password: secret
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/lookup
        dbCreate: update

environments:
    development:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: create-drop
                url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    test:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
                properties:
                   jmxEnabled: true
                   initialSize: 5
                   …
            lookup:
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
                username: lookup
                password: secret
                url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:lookup
                dbCreate: update
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        logSql: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver        
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        autoReconnect: true
        #url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:1521:DEV1(I remember in 3.0.9 this is under environments:development:dataSources:dataSource)
    dataSource2:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        logSql: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:1521:TEST1
        autoReconnect: true
    dataSource3:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        logSql: true
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
        username: MYUSER
        password: Password1
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:1521:PROD1
        autoReconnect: true
```

In controller:

```
static mapping = {
        datasources(['dataSource', 'dataSource2', 'dataSource3'])
        .....
}
```